# Can this be done in AS3?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have 2 frames which i would like to switch between when rotating a mobile device. These two frames have similar content except that the content in frame one consists of text and graphics and that in frame two consists of audio and graphics.

The idea is to allow the user to read the text when the device is in the upright position and when they rotate the device, they get the similar content but with audio.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [StageOrientationEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageOrientationEvent.html)?  You could catch Portrait/Landscape orientation there and switch frames based on what orientation, no?

Or continuously check the Stage Width/Height in onEnterFrame update and if height is bigger than width = Portrait, Else Landscape.

Comment: yes i did look at the same link above before posting but i could not figure out how to do it and thought i ask but thanks for the feedback.